# SBT Output for Kind Type

Tags: scala, sbt

With respect to type theory, the field of mathematics and computer science both tend to use the same notation for kinds and kinds construction, namely the symbols:

1. `*`
2. `->`

Haskell even adopts this notation:

```
Prelude> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

But in `sbt`, we get:

```
scala> :k Option
scala.Option's kind is F[+A]
```

The Haskell way is easier to understand as it directly matches the literature on type theory. Why did SBT not use the `*` and `->` notation? The only extra information I can see being imparted with the `sbt` way is the type variance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the verbose flag (-v)

```
scala> :k -v Option
scala.Option's kind is F[+A]
* -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```

Some more info:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/ (Ctrl+F :kind)

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2340